# pandas options: apply float format to floats in tuples

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which looks as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1.25,2.25], "B":[(3.25,4.23),(1.22,6.33)]})
      A             B
0  1.25  (3.25, 4.23)
1  2.25  (1.22, 6.33)
```

Now, I want all floats to have only one decimal when I print the dataframe. So I apply the following setting:

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.1f}'.format
```

So the dataframe now prints as follows:

```
    A             B
0 1.2  (3.25, 4.23)
1 2.2  (1.22, 6.33)
```

As you can see the floats in the tuples (B) did not get formatted, but the column consisting of pure floats did (A). Is there a way to set a global option to format floats that are also in tuples. I am aware that I could apply a format function to the column, but I am specifically asking for a global option similar to the above. Thanks!

The expected output is:

```
    A             B
0 1.2  (3.2, 4.2)
1 2.2  (1.2, 6.3)
```

Comment: `df = round(df,1); df['B'] = [(round(x,1), round(y,1)) for x,y in df['B']]`

Comment: As written in the post, I do not want to modify the dataframe. I am asking for a global option :) Similar to `pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.1f}'.format`

Comment: Don't think there's a global option to do the same. Got to apply a function to the column.

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done globally, but can be specified using pandas [styler](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html#Finer-Control:-Display-Values) on a column level:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [1.25, 2.25], 
    'B': [(3.25, 4.23), (1.22, 6.33)]
})

df.style.format({'A': '{:,.1f}', 'B': lambda x: '({:,.1f}, {:,.1f})'.format(*x)})
```